# Group call for multiple contacts at a time

Tags: android

In my application I have stored the phone contacts in app Database and created one group with multiple contacts (Database). When I click on that group (multiple contacts) I want to set a conference call with in the group at a time. 
Can anyone help me on this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried? what errors you facing...

Comment: I created group but I don't know what functionality to use to make a call to all the group contacts at a time

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the conference call function on a SIP Application Server. It would be possible to use FACs (Feature Access Codes) at server side.

For example,you will make a call with +11223344 and want to add +22334455 to the call by using makeAudioCall API with a supported FAC in the peerProfileUri, like "tel:*111#+11223344#+22334455#". Then you could set a conference call.